# Only add product to basket if product in specific category exists WooCoomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to add a product to my basket via an ACF field and have a working setup. However, Im trying to restrict the product to only show up if a product that belongs to a specific category is in the basket.

Code below in woocommerce.php. How do I restrict this for a specific product category?

```
function add_free_product_to_cart($item_key, $product_id, $quantity){

$product_ids = [];

$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

if(have_rows('theme_free_products', 'options')){
    while(have_rows('theme_free_products', 'options')){
        the_row();
        $start_date = get_sub_field('start_date');
        $end_date = get_sub_field('end_date');
        if(strtotime($start_date) <= $current_date && strtotime($end_date) > $current_date){
            $product_id = get_sub_field('product', false);
            $product_ids[] = $product_id;
        }
    }
}


if(!empty($product_ids)){
    foreach($product_ids as $product_id){
        $found = false;
        if(sizeof(WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0){
            foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values){
                $_product = $values['data'];

                if($_product->get_id() == $product_id){
                    $found = true;
                }
            }

        }

        if(!$found){
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
        }
    }
}

$warrantyProduct = get_field("warranty_product", "option",false);
if($product_id != $warrantyProduct && !get_field('product_has_no_warranty_product', $product_id)){
    $terms = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

    foreach($terms as $term){
        $categoryPossibleToAddWarranty = get_field("category_possible_to_add_warranty", "product_cat_" . $term->term_id);
        if($categoryPossibleToAddWarranty){

            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($warrantyProduct, $quantity, 0,[], ['connect_to_id' => $item_key]);

            //$cart_item_data

            break;
        }
    }
}

}
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_free_product_to_cart', 5, 3);
```

Comment: $category = get_term_by('name', 'warranty', 'category') helps?